# Disable CRM_Security XSS-Cleaner in codeigniter for a single textarea

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter project.

Now I trie to send a formula which contains html-script tags in a textarea.

```
    <textarea>
      <script src="linkto.js"></script>
      ... 
    </textarea>
```

My problem is, that a function in the core/CRM_Security.php replace this text (the script tag) with a "removed" text.

Normally it is the wanted way, to prevent XSS-injections and so, but in this single case, I need to send and get the script tags as they are.

Is there a way to mark this textarea to have a kind of exception for this?

Or in which another way, I can prevent to remove this by the xss_clean function?

Here a little bit of the code from the xss_clean function

```
public function xss_clean($str, $is_image = false)
 {
...
if (preg_match('/script|xss/i', $str)) {
                $str = preg_replace('#</*(?:script|xss).*?>#si', '[removed]', $str);
            }
...

}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable XSS prevention. It's there for a reason. When handling user input in your textarea, try to encode/decode the HTML entities.

PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: the problem is that the xss-clearner also looks for the word "script" etc

Comment: That's the purpose of XSS sanitizing. You don't want users to input executable scripts. 
You don't want to remove the xss cleaner function and shouldn't overwrite any of the framework's code anyways. It will be overridden at the first update and cause unwanted effects on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best but a easy way to solve it.

Before i send the datas, i replace the word "script" with a placeholder.

After, passing the xss-cleaner i replace the placeholder back to the word "script".

So i can store the wanted value  ;-)